# How to extend an activeRecord model in Yii

Tags: yii

I'm trying to create a form in Yii that is paged. Each page is for a group of fields. The best way to do this, I figured, would be to extend the ActiveRecord model and add a parameter for the current page. This also allows me to override the rules() methods with my own rules for the form itself.

My problem with this is, Yii doesn't allow us to natively extend models. I had to override the getMetaData() method because Yii runs self::model(get_class($this)) on itself, which ends up breaking everything.

Not only that, but I can't use findByPk because Yii relies heavily on the class name.

I know of tons of work arounds to make this work, but I'm wondering if I'm missing something.

Thanks,

Kyle

-- edit --

I totally figured it out, and I totally feel stupid. All I had to do with overwrite the model() method to return the current model class.

So:

```
class MyAr extends CActiveRecord {
    public static function model($class = __CLASS__){return parent::model($class);}
}

class ExtendedForm extends MyAr {
    public static function model($class = __CLASS__){return parent::model($class);}
}
```

Yeah ... I feel stupid.

Comment: If i understood you correctly, you want to make something like a wizard, right!! if so, why don't you use this behavior & configure it to your exact need? http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/wizard-behavior/

Comment: This actually looks really cool and may be my solution. I'll check it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To extend an ActiveRecord model, simply extend it! All you need to do is override the model method:

```
class MyAr extends CActiveRecord {
    public static function model($class = __CLASS__){return parent::model($class);}
}

class ExtendedForm extends MyAr {
    public static function model($class = __CLASS__){return parent::model($class);}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The model classes are subclasses of ActiveRecord, so you can override some vars/methods of ActiveRecord whitin them. What I mean is that there's no need to extend Activerecord... again! It is extended when defining models! So just add what whatever you need in there. Of course, this way has the inconvenience of adding the code manually in every model class. If it is too much, and if you're using gii, then you could just modify the code template that gii uses to generate the models.

Comment: I was hoping to leave out all the specific code to my form. My Model doesnt need all that information.